# Pull Test Cases from MTM where I have not passed "Parameter Values"

Tags: mtm

Assume I have 1000 test cases in MTM calling shared steps with required parameters.Now I want to know all the Test Cases by some query or script mechanism where any of the parameter value is missing.

Any direction will help.

Comment: Is using TFS APIs an option? If yes, then I think this should be possible using WorkItem queries [blogs.msdn.com/b/aseemb/archive/2012/08/07/code-snippets-on-test-management-apis.aspx].

Comment: yes, that looks to be one of the option, will be trying the same in case of no other options..

Answer (score 0):

You can use TFS APIs (if thats an option). You can run WorkItem queries and get the required info. [blogs.msdn.com/b/aseemb/archive/2012/08/07/code-snippets-on-test-management-api‌​s.aspx](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aseemb/archive/2012/08/07/code-snippets-on-test-management-api%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bs.aspx)